# my loop is not working properly - java

Tags: java

I made a method which is in s seperate class the method is a simple loop that allows me enter 5 numbers and then return them in an array so i can call them in my main

This is the method:

```
  public static List<Integer> getJackTicket()
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Integer> jackTickA = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5; ++i)
    {    
       System.out.print("Number " + i + "");
       int value = Integer.parseInt(s.next()); 
       jackTickA.add(value);
    }
    return jackTickA;
}
```

And this is how i m calling it

```
  System.out.println("Please enter your ticket numbers ");
                JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();
                System.out.println("Your ticket numbers are: " + JackpotTicket.getJackTicket());
```

it should ask me for 5 numbers and after i enter them it displays them, however it is asking me for numbers 1 through 5 than ask me for 1 through 5 again and only display the last 5.

[this is what it showing when i run the program](http://gyazo.com/9726904f8fd8564542015f48af7294d2)

Any ideas what i m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();` twice. So it will execute it twice.
Remove the call that is not in the output.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the method twice, so of course it's going to ask the user twice.

When you call it the first time, store the returned `List<Integer>` so you can refer to it again later.

```
System.out.println("Please enter your ticket numbers ");
List<Integer> numbers = JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();
System.out.println("Your ticket numbers are: " + numbers );
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are calling the method *twice*.

You may want to store the result of `JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();` in a variable:

```
List l = JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();
```

Then, you can use it.

**Remember** Every time that Java finds `JackpotTicket.getJackTicket()`, it will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You called `getJackTicket()` twice instead of saving its result and reusing it for output:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your ticket numbers ");
final List<Integer> res = JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();
System.out.println("Your ticket numbers are:");
for(final Integer i : res) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Since `getJackTicket()` always askes the user for new input, your user was asked twice and the first result was used for anything.

---

Also, if you want to format your results in one line, this might be useful:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your ticket numbers ");
final List<Integer> res = JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();
System.out.print("Your ticket numbers are: ");
for(final Integer i : res) {
    System.out.print(i + " "); // don't add \n to end line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling your method twice, so it executes twice. You need to store its results in a variable that you can later output:

```
List<Integer> numbers = JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();
System.out.println("Your ticket numbers are: " + numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Please enter your ticket numbers ");
remove this call --> JackpotTicket.getJackTicket();
System.out.println("Your ticket numbers are: " + JackpotTicket.getJackTicket());
```

### Your final call should be:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your ticket numbers ");
System.out.println("Your ticket numbe`enter code here`rs are: " + JackpotTicket.getJackTicket());
```